# export variable in google cloud instance rhel7

Tags: java, linux, google-compute-engine, rhel7

I created an instance from the RHEL7 image.

Installed java at `/opt/jdk1.7` and edited `/etc/enviroment` to contain `PATH=/opt/jdk1.7/bin:$PATH`

Now performed a reboot.

Now when I try to login it allow to login using first part of email id then it ask for passpharse.

Now I am login as `xyz`.

Now I type `java -version` it gives me the correct version and also 
`echo $PATH` prints the correct `path`.

Now I switch to root using `sudo su`
and  `whoami` prints `root` and `path` get change and it does not cantain the java bin path in it.

How to export variables globally ?

PS: one strange thing is after i switch to `root` and again switch back to `xyz`. the `path` doesnt contain the path to `java bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable expansion does not work in /etc/environment. Only absolute value assignments can be put in this file.
For e.g

```
T1=hithere
T2=X-$T1
```

after you reboot,

```
echo $T2
```

would print X-$T1 , though T1's value would be set as intended.

so put it in ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, or /etc/profile etc